# Build library Github with Jitpack include dependencies

Tags: android, github, jitpack

I'm building a library with jitpack.io I was able to build and compile into the application successfully, but the problem here is that in the library there includes a number of other libraries compiled into

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.1'
 implementation 'com.appnext.sdk:banners:2.4.2.472'
 implementation 'com.appnext.sdk:ads:2.4.2.472'
 implementation 'com.appnext.sdk:native-ads2:2.4.2.472'
 implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
```

so when I compiled the library into my application and called it, it reportedly did not find the class I was including into libraries(org.jsoup., com.appnext., ..). If I want to use I have to re-declare the libraries on again in my application. Is there a way to not do this, as includes the library inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and apparently it's a bug in maven gradle plugin v1.5; problem solved after my plugin version is updated to 2.1.

Issue: https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/issues/61

Related Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51190164/1640033

Comment: Thank @SpringMaple, It really works. I just modified it and it worked